# Rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 upgrade cause wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've upgraded from Rails 4.0.0 to Rails 4.1.0 .

Now I got this error:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

```
 @courses = Course.all(:conditions =>{ :lecturer_id => session[:user_id] })
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Lösung ist: @courses = Course.where(:lecturer_id => session[:user_id]).all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use *Active Record's* `.where()` method:

```
@courses = Course.where(lecturer_id: session[:user_id])
```